# Getting row of UITableView cell on button press

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview controller that displays a row of cells. Each cell has 3 buttons. I have numbered the tags for each cell to be 1,2,3. The problem is I don't know how to find on which cell a button is being pressed. I'm currently only getting the sender's tag when one of the buttons has been pressed. Is there a way to get the cell row number as well when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You should really be using this method instead:

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

Swift version:

```
let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint(), to:tableView)
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at:buttonPosition)
```

That will give you the `indexPath` based on the position of the button that was pressed.  Then you'd just call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if you need the cell or `indexPath.row` if you need the row number.

If you're paranoid, you can check for `if (indexPath) ...` before using it just in case the `indexPath` isn't found for that point on the table view.

All of the other answers are likely to break if Apple decides to change the view structure.

Comment: this, a million times. *none* of the others worked, but this was perfect and by far the simplest solution

Comment: This answer works because it is **the correct** solution. The others are workarounds. Thanks!

Comment: In case you _don't_ have **self.tableview**, please refer to my answer on this page.

Comment: This worked for me once I realized my sender was the wrong class. Fixed it to be the UIButton pressed, and now it is working!

Comment: This is working, but the UIButton in the last row of the table will change text when any of the other UIButton are selected. Any advice for what I should check?

Comment: just remember the method is `convertPoint:*to*View` not `convertPoint:*from*View`. I used Xcode autocomplete and ended up with fromView method only leading to not working...

Comment: See answer below for swift 3. @iwasrobbed : feel free to incorporate my answer into yours.

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: Check this out : Simple, Quick & Easy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156685/5846076

Comment: i've been looking for this solution for a few days now. Works perfectly fine. But i have a few questions. Does this have any drawbacks? What is difference re-defining a button tag? Ok i can see that it would be hard getting correct indexPath when re-defining a tag if you have few sections in table :)

Answer (score 40):

Edit: This answer is outdated.  [Please use this method instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/308315)

---

Try this:

```
-(void)button1Tapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)[senderButton superview];
    UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[buttonCell superview];
    NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:buttonCell];
    NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
    NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
}
```

Edit: If you are using contentView, use this for buttonCell instead:

```
UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)senderButton.superview.superview;
```

Comment: You're not supposed to add subviews to the cell itself but only to its `contentView` property - so this solution doesn't really work.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @H2CO3 and I also don't think this should be done by referencing superviews.  Please see a better way below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/308315

Comment: @minimalpop can you please change the correct answer ? to have a better Q/A !

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS 7. Use indexPathForRowAtPoint: answer below

Comment: I tried the same version with an UICollectionView and works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @iWasRobbed improved his answer below to use `convertPoint` and `indexPathForRowAtPoint`.  Please change the accepted answer, thank you!

Comment: You can use this method, but you should have an intermediate step of getting the contentView from the button superview, then get the actual cell from the contentView superview

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend this way to fetch indexPath of cell which has any custom subview - (**compatible with iOS 7 as well as all previous versions**)

```
-(void)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
//- (void)cellSubviewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
//    UIView *parentCell = gestureRecognizer.view.superview;
    UIView *parentCell = sender.superview;

    while (![parentCell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
        parentCell = parentCell.superview;
    }

    UIView *parentView = parentCell.superview;

    while (![parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
        parentView = parentView.superview;
    }


    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)parentView;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)parentCell];

    NSLog(@"indexPath = %@", indexPath);
}
```

This doesn't require `self.tablview` either.

*Also, notice the commented code which is useful if you want the same through a @selector of UIGestureRecognizer added to your custom subview.*

Comment: What about if i need data found in the uitableviewcontroller?

Comment: Good answer .If you have a searchbar and would like to know which table is used at the moment you can use this also.

Comment: table cell hierarchy changed? can you help me to understand that what changes has happened and can it be change further?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways:

1. @H2CO3 is right.  You can do what @user523234 suggested, but with a small change, to respect the UITableViewCellContentView that should come in between the UIButton and the UITableViewCell.  So to modify his code:

   ```
   - (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender
   {
       UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
       UITableViewCellContentView *cellContentView = (UITableViewCellContentView *)senderButton.superview;
       UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = (UITableViewCell *)cellContentView.superview;
       UITableView* tableView = (UITableView *)tableViewCell.superview;
       NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [tableView indexPathForCell:tableViewCell];
       NSInteger rowOfTheCell = pathOfTheCell.row;
       NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
   }
   ```
2. If you create a custom UITableViewCell (your own subclass), then you can simply call `self` in the IBAction. You can link the IBAction function to your button by using storyboard or programmatically when you set up the cell.

   ```
   - (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender
   {
       UITableView* tableView = (UITableView *)self.superview;
       NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [tableView indexPathForCell:self];
       NSInteger rowOfTheCell = pathOfTheCell.row;
       NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you add buttons to cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then what I would do is to create a custom class subclass `UIButton`, add a **tag** called `rowNumber`, and append that data while you adding button to cell.

Comment: This is fine, but there's no reason to create a subclass of `UIButton` for it. `tag` is a common property of `UIView`.

Comment: Don't know what was I thinking and assume **UI** something is not a **UI**, thanks for correction!

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way:

- Get the point of touch in tableView
- Then get index path of cell at point
- The index path contains row index

The code is:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:theTableView];

    NSIndexPath *theIndexPath = [theTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    NSInteger theRowIndex = theIndexPath.row;
    // do your stuff here
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

Note: This should really go in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/5276890) above, except that [meta frowns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291860/handling-suggested-edits-user-updated-answer-for-updated-library) upon such edits.

```
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableView)
   let index = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
}
```

Two minor comments:

1. The default function has sender type as Any, which doesn't have convert.
2. CGPointZero can be replaced by CGPoint()

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to check the tag of the button's superview or even higher in the view hierarchy (if the button is in the cell's content view).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share code in swift -

```
extension UITableView
{
    func indexPathForCellContainingView(view1:UIView?)->NSIndexPath?
    {
        var view = view1;
        while view != nil {
            if (view?.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) == true)
            {
                return self.indexPathForCell(view as! UITableViewCell)!
            }
            else
            {
                view = view?.superview;
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: sender.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableView)) else {
        return
    }
    // do something
}
```