# Pass an argument to selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UIButton inside my custom cell and I want to trigger an action when the user presses that button BUT I need to know from which row the UIButton was pressed.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;

    ...

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void)buttonPressedAction:(UIButton *)button
{
    //int row = indexPath.row;
    //NSLog(@"ROW: %i",row);
}
```

How do I pass the indexPath as argument to my selector?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504421/getting-row-of-uitableview-cell-on-button-press/7505025#7505025

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either set the tag property of the button to the row number:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and retrieve it using

```
NSInteger row = button.tag;
```

or set the index path object itself as an associated object to the button:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(button, "IndexPath", indexPath);
```

and

```
NSIndexPath *ip = objc_getAssociatedObject(button, "IndexPath");
```

Comment: Thanks! The associated object to the button looks like an elegant solution

Comment: @Prince exactly as I wrote in the example.

Comment: its giving warning implicit declaration of 'objc_setAssociatedObject'. As i need to ignore warning, i m using xcode 4.4.1

Comment: solved by #import <objc/runtime.h>. Thanks @H2CO3 wonderful answer

Comment: if i can use the method to pass a nsobject for example naaarray or custom object as People?

Answer (score 2):

while adding the button on the custom cell, u can add the `tag` property of UIButton as

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
sampleButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and then when u call, u can check the tag

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if(sender.tag==0)
    {
      //perform action
    }
}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: You have to declare the button as UIButton, else the property accessor won't work. (I didn't -1, btw).

Answer (score 1):

Simple set the button tag ..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;

    ...

    [button setTag = indexPath.row]; // Set button tag

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:)
                                            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    - (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        int row = [button superview].tag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its even simple than setting a tag. Try this..

To get The indexPath try the following code.

```
UIView *contentView = (UIVIew *)[button superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
```

OR

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[(UIVIew *)[button superview] superview]];
```