# How to find a cell textfield outside of a tableView delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, ui-design

I have a custom tableView cell with a textfield. Now, I want to recognise the textField outside of the tableView delegate method. I tried this-

```
UIView *cell = textField;
[cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]];
```

but it's not working.

Comment: seems like you need whole cell, not just textfield. you need to provide more context for this...

Comment: Check below link once it might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/24246881/5184217

Answer (score 0):

To get concrete cell from table view you need to know index path of this cell. Then you need to do:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];  //you should set your indexes of row and section instead of zeros
MyCustomCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now if text field is a property of your custom cell you can get it using `cell.myTextField`

For example:

```
UITextField *textField = cell.myTextField;
```

Now you can do what you want with it.