# how to get indexpath uitextfield inside tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

i just know to get indexpath button inside tableviewcell like this

> CGPoint center= [sender center]; CGPoint rootViewPoint = [[sender superview] convertPoint:center toView:_tableView1];
>   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView1 indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint]; NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

but i need know about textfield  thx for helping me guys!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i have label (for question label) and textfield(for answer textfield) inside tableviewcell, but i need to input text in textfield.. the problem is in my API should looping parameter ANSWER (this should in uitextfield), like ANSWER1 ANSWER2 ANSWER3, i already declare parameter ANSWER in my uitextfield but when i complite insert text in all looping uitextfield and klik OK, my parameter ANSWER still empty, because uitextfield dont know which one is ANSWER1 or ANSWER2 or ANSWER3, its should consecutive from top to end looping..

Comment: i want use tag , like i succes get indexpath my button before, like this self.button.tag=indexPath.row;

but i dont how to get indexpath use tag with uitextfield

Comment: See this previous post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319058/how-to-get-cell-indexpath-in-uitextfield-delegate-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another method to get the index row!

In cellForRow do this:

```
textField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

In the textField method do this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSInteger row = textField.tag;    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
}
```

Comment: where i should use *indexpath?

Comment: The question was how to get the indexPath. It is your choice where to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the `indexPath` of the cell in which the textfield is contained you need to do a couple of things.

1. Make the `viewController` class the delegate of the textField in the tableView's cell
2. Implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method of textField's `delegateProtocol` in your `viewController`'s class like this

`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   //Here you can you the same logic to find the indexPath of the cell like you use in case of a button.
}`