# using objc_setAssociatedObject to pass UIButton @selector argument for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm attempting to implement a suggestion in this post: [Pass an argument to selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297511/pass-an-argument-to-selector/12297575#12297575) to pass an `@selector` argument to a `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell` using `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject`.  The way I have it coded, it always ends up passing the row of whatever the last cell was that it created/loaded.  Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *mainLabel;
    soundButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    soundButton.tag = 33;
        [soundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(soundButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [soundButton setFrame:CGRectMake(210,3,68, 37)];

         [soundButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"musicNote"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         [cell.contentView addSubview:soundButton];
    } else {

        soundButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:33];
    }
    objc_setAssociatedObject(soundButton, "IndexPath", indexPath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    return cell;
}

-(void)soundButtonAction
{
    NSIndexPath *ip = objc_getAssociatedObject(soundButton, "IndexPath");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `soundButton` is an ivar in your class? it is get override every time a cell is requested so you only get the last one.

also I think it is not good idea to use `"IndexPath"` as the key.

```
static char indexPathKey; // use address of indexPathKey as key

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *mainLabel;
    soundButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    soundButton.tag = 33;
        [soundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(soundButtonAction:) /*extra :*/ forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [soundButton setFrame:CGRectMake(210,3,68, 37)];

         [soundButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"musicNote"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         [cell.contentView addSubview:soundButton];
    } else {

        soundButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:33];
    }
    objc_setAssociatedObject(soundButton, &indexPathKey, indexPath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    return cell;
}

-(void)soundButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *ip = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, &indexPathKey);
```