# how to find index path within UITableView when a custom button is pressed

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a tableview of which each cell has a custom button.  I have this method which tells me the index path where the button was located.  The method below works fantastic in iOS 6, but I am not sure how to get the same result in iOS 5 since indexPathForItem is only available in iOS 6.0 and later.

```
- (IBAction) checkUncheck:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *sendingButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell =  (UITableViewCell *)[[sendingButton superview] superview];
    PDFFile *newPDF = [_pdfDocument.pdfFileList objectAtIndex: cell.tag];
    [newPDF setCheck: [NSNumber numberWithBool: ![newPDF.check boolValue]]];

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: cell.tag inSection: 0];

    [_table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: path, nil] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: I think the actual answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/365188

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting row of UITableView cell on button press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504421/getting-row-of-uitableview-cell-on-button-press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 methods to find NSIndexPath in TableView

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;                         // returns nil if point is outside table
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;                      // returns nil if cell is not visible
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect;                              // returns nil if rect not valid
```

You use indexPathForItem is not good method, try

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell] ;
```

Comment: Replacing this:
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: cell.tag inSection: 0];
    
With this:
NSIndexPath *path = [_table indexPathForCell: cell];
worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom UITableViewCell subclass. When you configure your (hopefully reused) cell in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, pass the index path (row and section) to the newly configured cell (i.e., each cell 'knows' its current index path).

Next, make the custom button notify the parent cell when tapped through the usual target-action mechanism. When the button is tapped, have the cell broadcast a notification with itself as the `object` property. Your table view controller can listen to this notification, extract the cell from it and the index path from the cell.

e.g., in the custom table cell implementation (MyTableViewCell.m):

```
- (void) didTapButton:(id) sender

{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UserTappedCellButton" object:self];
}
```

in the view controller:

```
- (id) init 
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didTapCellButton:)
                                                     name:@"UserTappedCellButton"
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) didTapCellButton:(NSNotifcation*) notification
{
   MyCustomTableViewCell* cell = (MyCustomTableViewCell*)[notification object];

   NSIndexPath* path = [cell path]; // <-- You must define this property 

   // Use index path...
}
```

Perhaps there's a simpler/smarter way, but this one is pretty straightforward and comes to mind first...