# Custom delete button for UITableViewCell without editing mode?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made a UITableViewCell nib with a button on it.  When the button is pressed, I want to delete the cell.  The table view isn't in editing mode and I'm not using a standard UITableViewCell delete button.

I could store the row number in the button tag from cellForRowAtIndexPath, and use that to determine the row to delete, but when a cell is deleted, the button tags will be incorrect.

Any ideas how I can identify what button press relates to what row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/308315):

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your button is a subview of cell's content view (as it should be). You can get the index path for the cell with button like this:

```
UIView *cellContentView = yourButton.superview;
UITableViewCell *cell = cellContentView.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Then, just delete the cell:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Apologies, but lootsch implementation works better for me.  Upvoted anyways.

Answer (score 0):

if the method the button calls has a signature like:

```
-(void)action:(id)sender;
```

sender will be the UIButton that called the action so:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = [[button superview] superview];
```

should get you what you want.