# Get indexPath from tableViewCell class

Tags: ios, button, uitableview

I have a button (action) connected to my UITableViewCell class. How do I get indexPath of tableView from tableViewCell class?

```
@implement myTableViewCell

-(IBAction)buttonPressed{
    // Do something to get indexPath?
}
```

Comment: I wish to get indexPath from UITableViewCell class, not from UITableView class.

Comment: The most simple solution is to add a index property for your custom cell and keep updating it.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19441029/1187415 to the "possible duplicate" should work even from the table view cell.

Comment: @MartinR I just saw it, I get error on the first line 
"UIView *parentCell = sender.superview;"
The error message is Property 'superview' not found on object of type '__strong id'. What does it means?

Comment: @user3322987: Declaring the method as `-(void)button1Tapped:(UIButton *)sender` should solve that problem.

Comment: (@user3322987: But check if a *cell* should really "know" its index path within the table view. Perhaps all tasks involving the index path are better delegated to the table view controller.)

Comment: @MartinR all solutions that get indexPath from tableView class are directing my question toward "duplicate of other question". Just want to figure out a way to get parent's tableView indexPath from cell class.

Comment: I agree it shouldnt know its path, but I provided you the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in CustomCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn;
```

in tableView dataSource file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

//button action
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIControl *)sender event:(id)event{
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView  indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPos];
   if(indexPath != nil){
       //to do with indexPath 
   }
}
```

//button action in cell class

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)btn event:(id)event{
    UIView *superView = [btn superview];
    while (superView && ![superView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        superView = [superView superview];
    }

    if ([superView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)superView;
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPos];
        if(indexPath != nil){
            NSLog(@"tableView.row:%d", indexPath.row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My IBAction is in the Cell class. Just want to figure out a way to get parent's tableView indexPath from cell class.

Comment: @user3322987 I have edited my code. This is work for me nicely.

Comment: cell is only a view which will be reused by tableView, it can't have any indexPath information when ignore tableView actually use it.

Comment: Your answer works well, but my question haven't solve yet. Anyway thanks!

Comment: If you really want to do this in cell class ,just use `[btn superview]` recursive to find the tableView class, then use my method to get the indexPath, I have edited my answer, hope to help you.

Comment: I've looked everywhere - tried every thing. This was the only solution that worked. Thanks a lot. +1.. (I'm not sure why the action in the custom cell class is needed.. It wasn't for me)

Answer (score 0):

Like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/308315):

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

Comment: The IBAction is in the UITableViewCell.m , how do I point to parent tableView?

Comment: add a delegate protocol to your `TableViewCell`, wich should tell your tableView, that it was pushed.

Comment: I mean what should I cast on "self.tableView" from the code below?

CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];

Comment: do you only need to know the index path inside the `tableViewCell`? Then you could add a `indexPath` property your `tableViewCell` and set it from your `tableView`. Then you would know it, when the action is called.

Comment: Just want to figure out a way to get parent's tableView indexPath from cell class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add action to your button with sender:

```
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then:

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

}
```

Comment: The IBAction is in the UITableViewCell.m , how do I point to parent tableView?

Answer (score 0):

1. get the table from the cell. place this inside the cell

   ```
   - (UITableView*)tableView {
       if (tableView == nil) {
           tableView = (UITableView*)self.superview;
           while (tableView && ![tableView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
               tableView = (UITableView*)tableView.superview;
           }
       }
       return tableView;
   }
   ```
2. inside your IBAction ask for the indexpath

   ```
   NSIndexPath *p = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:self];
   ```

TADA ;)

Comment: I'm wondering how to get cell's superview.

Comment: How to "get the table from the cell"?

Comment: I dont get your issue.. that 100% what the code under 1. does