# How to get indexpath of the selected row?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I am developing a messenger app. I have a tableview with custom cell containing an imageview and a couple of labels.

I want to load different controllers on tapping different UI elements. To be specific, I want controllerA to be loaded when imageView is tapped and controllerB when the rest of the row is selected.

I placed a button on top of imageview and made a customcellclass delegate to notify my tableviewcontroller when imageview is tapped with the aid of that button - now how am i supposed to get indexpath for the tapped row imageView ??

//MyCustomClassMethod

```
-(IBAction)loadProfileButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    [self.loadProfileDelegate takeMeToProfile];
}
```

//i am implementing this method in my tableview controller

```
-(void)takeMeToProfile{
//need indexpath here
}
```

Comment: I gt ur question but can u paste code so we can edit in your code... or we can give suggestion in your code only.

Comment: As i gt ur questionm, I can suggest you that pass indexpath and tag in delegate method and check if tag is of imageview than open ControllerA else ControllerB

Comment: You r welcome , Glad I could help to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have `indexpath` for what you want to achieve. When you add these custom views just provide them with a tag to identify them when button click event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table view is named tableView, and that you get reference of the tapped image in a method where you grab the sender:

```
CGPoint imagePosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:imagePosition];
```

[All the credit to this so answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/1720332)

Answer (score 0):

It's common to pass a reference to `self` in delegate methods for the custom cells so that you can trace the `indexPath` from the parent VC. Try switching this:

```
-(void)takeMeToProfile
```

with this:

```
-(void)customCell:(CustomCell*)cell didTapTakeMeToProfile;
```

When you implement this in your `CustomCell` file, you'll simply call `[self.loadProfileDelegate customCell:self didTapTakeMeToProfile]`. Now that you have a reference to the cell, you can call `tableView:indexPathForCell:` from the parent VC and use the resulting `NSIndexPath` however you see fit.