# How to change element title inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a button on custom tableviewcell. I've been able add action to this button by add target like below code:

```
    var playButton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as? UIButton
    var sender : UIButton = UIButton()
    playButton?.addTarget(self, action: "playPost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    playButton?.layer.setValue(object["previewUrl"] as? String, forKey: "songUrl")
    playButton?.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
```

But, how can I change it's title whenever I clicked this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function is `playPost()`, you could change the value passed in (which is the `sender` of the function, by default) like this:

```
func playPost(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.setTitle("New title", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I looking for. Is it possible to change other element title on the same cell?

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra Yes you could. I'd set the `tag` of the button to the cell's `row`, then call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, constructing the index path using the button's tag. Make sense?

Comment: I don't get it, could you give some reference or code snippet?

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra Here's another way to do it, which may be better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/1145804 Please note that this is not pertinent to the original question you posted, so if my answer helps, please accept it. If this linked thread doesn't help answer your other question, please post a new one.

Comment: ok, thanks for your suggestion. I think I'm gonna make another post

Answer (score 0):

You can Change `UIButton` title by using `setTitle` Method

**Example**

```
    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    button.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "pressButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)


   func pressButton(sender:UIButton)
   {
      if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Start"
      {
        sender.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
      }
      else
      {
        sender.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
      }
   }
```